# Today Extension widget freezes when the main app is updated

Tags: ios, crashlytics, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I am suffering from Today Extension freezing issue when the main app is updated. In detail, I recently found that Today Extension freezes after updating the main app from Crashlytics Beta service. After that, all of touchable things like a button does not work. I tried to reinstall the widget by setting menu supported by Today but failed.

The only way to solve this symptom is rebooting iPhone device. You know, however, this is not proper solution.

What makes the widget freeze after updating a main app?

Comment: I experience the exact same thing :(

Comment: Did you only experience this when updating via Crashlytics? So no risk when updating an App Store application? Did you tell Crashlytics / Fabric support about this and, if so, did you get any feedback from them?

Comment: Now, I think this problem could be found via Crashlytics. This hasn't been raise if it is from App Store.

Comment: @KyokookHwang Can you please share the solution to this issue?

Comment: @ParthBhatt I realized that problem was caused by Beta service by Fabric.io. Now, I dont meet that issue again.