# TodayExtension's ViewWillAppear not called after scrolling to the top

Tags: ios, objective-c, widget, today-extension, ios9-today-widget

I use tableview to display widget content, and everything just works well except I scroll the TodayExtension to the bottom and scroll back to the top (**`ViewWillDisappear`** called) and as I try to scroll down, the **`viewWillAppear`** will never be called, thus I cannot tap on the table. However, if I drag the extension again, or switch from Notifications, tableview is enable for tapping.

The mysterious part is, if I choose **edit > remove > re-add**, this bug never shows up. but it just makes no sense if I do so every time compiling codes (not even for users to update app from AppStore)

I've searched similar questions on forums, but have no solution yet.

1. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16348
2. http://www.openradar.me/22545070
3. [Today Extension widget freezes when the main app is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937104/today-extension-widget-freezes-when-the-main-app-is-updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to update this question for almost 1 year.

I finally found the reason anyway.
It's apple's bug that it only occurs in development mode. once it is released the problem will no longer occur.